# Make intpreters from Cygwin available in windows

Tags: cygwin

I have ruby, ocaml, and python available under cygwin.

How can I use them outside of cygwin (e.g. `gem` be available in say, powershell)

Answer (score 0):

```
<windows path to bash> -c <cygwin path to command>
```

so for example, from the desktop I can run "D:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe" -c /bin/python.

However, they're (sort of) already available. if you check out /bin, you'll find executable files that you can run if you need to - for example, I found python2.7.exe.